# airflow dag runs everyday even the schedule is only for 3rd saturday of month

Tags: python, cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I have a job to run on 3rd Saturday of every month. But I see the dag is running on everyday at 00:00 and if it is 3rd saturday of month then it runs twice a day (00:00 and 09:15). Here is my below dag and schedule.

```
dag = DAG(
      dag_id='JOB1'
      start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
      schedule_interval='15 9 * * 6#3',
      default_args=args,
      max active runs=1,
      catchup=False
)
```

Airflow version- 2.1.3

Please suggest me, If am I doing anything wrong in my schedule.

Comment: how did you overcome this?